# Accept array from struct array

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I need to print all students which average grade is bigger or equal to given average.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct Student {
  char name[20], surname[20];
  int grades[50];
  int number_of_grades;
};
void print_average(struct Student students[], int n, double avarage) {
  double avarage_grade;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    avarage_grade =
        (double)(students[i].grades[i]) / students[i].number_of_grades;
    if (avarage_grade >= avarage)
      printf("%s %s\n", students[i].surname, students[i].name);
  }
}
int main() {
  struct Student students[] = {{"Meho", "Behic", {10, 9}, 2},
                               {"Meho", "Aehic", {10, 8}, 2},
                               {"Meho", "Cehic", {10, 9, 8, 7, 6}, 5},
                               {"Meho", "Dehic", {6, 9}, 2},
                               {"Meho", "Zehic", {10}, 1},
                               {"Meho", "Oehic", {10, 9, 9, 9}, 4}};
  print_average(students, 6, 9.2);
  return 0;
}
```

Program should print only two students. This doesn't print anything because I made a mistake in accessing array *grades* elements.
Could you help me fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you calculate the average, you're only taking a *single* grade and dividing it by the number of grades.  You need to add up the grades first.

```
void print_average(struct Student students[], int n, double avarage) {
  double avarage_grade;
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j=0, avarage_grade=0; j<students[i].number_of_grades; j++) {
        avarage_grade += students[i].grades[j];
    }
    avarage_grade /= students[i].number_of_grades;
    if (avarage_grade >= avarage)
      printf("%s %s\n", students[i].surname, students[i].name);
  }
}
```